# how to restrict dates in datepicker using jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

I am trying to restrict the dates in the date picker and would like to make available only for 2012 and 2013 in the date-picker.  how would i do that?  I am not sure the syntax of j-query so i can restrict it.  thanks  this is what i have so far.
here is my j-query

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
             $(document).ready(function () {
                 $('.datepicker').datepicker({ minDate: -20, maxDate: "+1M +10D" });
             });
    </script>
```

Comment: http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-maxDate <-- This link shows that `"y" for years, "m" for months, "w" for weeks, and "d" for days`

Comment: Oh I think I misunderstood your question..  You want those dates ranges for 2012 and 2013?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should assign Date objects to the two fields:

```
$('.datepicker').datepicker({ minDate: new Date(2012, 0, 1) , maxDate: new Date(2013, 11, 31) });
```